# Different results in LU decomposition in Matlab and R packages (Matrix and pracma)

Tags: r, matlab, matrix

I'm trying to understand the algorithm used by Matlab and R in LU-decomposition.
Suppose I want to LU-decompose the matrix:

$$
    A=
    \begin{bmatrix}
    5 & 6 & 5 & 8 \\
    10 & 15 & 12 & 13 \\
    15 & 12 & 15 & 28 \\
    20 & 33 & 22 & 32 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

## Using R

The `pracma` library gives me the following result:

```
require(pracma)
A <- matrix(c(5,6,5,8,10,15,12,13,15,12,15,28,20,33,22,32), byrow=T, ncol=4)
LUdec <- pracma::lu(A)
all(A == LUdec$L %*% LUdec$U)
  [1] TRUE
```

$$
    U=
    \begin{bmatrix}
    5 & 6 & 5 & 8 \\
    0 & 3 & 2 & -3 \\
    0 & 0 & 4 & -2 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 7 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

$$
    L=
    \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    2 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
    3 & -2 & 1 & 0 \\
    4 & 3 & -1 & 1 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

Thus solving $A=LU$.

The `pracma` library propose a permutation vector $\mathbf{P}^\top=\mathbf{(4,1,2,3)}^\top$, using the `lufact` function:

```
lufact(A)$perm
  [1] 4 1 2 3
```

The `Matrix` library returns a different results, adding an (unnecessary?) permutation matrix, and consequently completely different L and U matrices:

```
require(Matrix)
A <- matrix(c(5,6,5,8,10,15,12,13,15,12,15,28,20,33,22,32), byrow=T, ncol=4)
mat_lu = Matrix::lu(A)
expand(mat_lu)

P1 <- expand(mat_lu)$P
U1 <- expand(mat_lu)$U
L1 <- expand(mat_lu)$L
all(P1 %*% A == L1 %*% U1)
  [1] TRUE
```

Thus solving $PA=LU$, where $\mathbf{P}^\top=\mathbf{(4,3,2,1)}^\top$, or

$$
    P=
    \begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

## Using Matlab

The `lu` functions returns the following results:

```
A = [5 6 5 8; 10 15 12 13; 15 12 15 28; 20 33 22 32];
[L,U,P] = lu(A)
```

The three matrices obtained in Matlab are the same of `Matrix::lu(A)` in R.

## Question

Now my question is: why both Matlab and `Matrix::lu` compute a permutation matrix, while `pracma::lu` does not? What is the need of a partial pivoting, in my specific example, where no pivotal-0 appears during the Gaussian elimination method? Why the permutation vectors are different in `pracma` and `Matrix`?

Comment: This question confuses me. "why both Matlab and Matrix::lu compute a permutation matrix, while pracma::lu does not?" What these functions do is documented. Why `pracma::lu` doesn't pivot, is a question about the motivation of the programmer. I don't see how this can be answered by anyone else. But maybe the quote from the documentation is helpful to you: "This function is not meant to process huge matrices or linear systems of equations. Without pivoting it may also be harmed by considerable inaccuracies."

Comment: @Roland thanks for the answer. However, why performing a partial pivoting gaussian elimination, while without permutation the resulting L and U matrices are much more simple?